# How to kill a process by PID using java on a remote computer?

Tags: java, pid, psexec

I am using java to run a Psexec command to excute a process on a remote computer:
**Java** -> **Psexec** -> remote computer starts a **process**.

I have the PID of that process.
Is there a way to have the remote computer terminate that process?
Maybe using psexec to tell the remote computer to run a cmd command to terminate it ?

Comment: You can do it with `psexec`. No need for Java at all.

Answer (score 0):

If both your local and your remote machine are UNIX-based (i.e. macOS or Ubuntu) then you can use `ssh`:

```
ssh user@remote_host 'kill -9 <pid>'
```